# Each Node of data perform separate database request

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

below is the GraphQLObject Fields

```
    userId: {
        type: GraphQLID,
        resolve: obj => {
            console.log(obj._id);
            return obj._id;
        }
    },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
    lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
```

mine server sents multiple request equally as of mine documents, here it will send 5 different request.

how can i optimize these request get all data in one request

```
    589800cf39b58b29c4de90dd
--------------------------------
    58980673e7c9a733009091d1
--------------------------------
    58985339651c4a266848be42
--------------------------------
    589aac5f884b062b979389bc
--------------------------------
    589aad9d24989c2d50f2a25a
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return many objects like `user` using one request? And each `user` would have one of `id` specified above?

Comment: yes i would like to get all the users in `[]` and perform one request and as make as much as less db request

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you could create a `query` method which would accept an `array` as a parameter, which would be an array of IDs in this case.

```js
getUsers: {
    type: new GraphQLList(User),
    args: {
        ids: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)))
        } 
    },
    resolve: (root, args, context) => {
        let query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ANY($1)';

        return pgClient.query(query, [args.ids], (err, result) => {
            // here you would access all returned rows in the result object
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

The `query` variable would differ depending on what database you are using. In this example I have used the `node-postgres` module for PostgreSQL. However, the concept is the same - use array of ids to perform single query returning all users.

And then you could call that query:

```
query getUsers($ids: [ID!]!) {
    getUsers(ids: $ids){
        id
        email
        ...
    }
}

// and the variables below
{
    ids: ['id#1', 'id#2', 'id#3']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for Dataloader, a library from Facebook specifically for batching together queries like this:

https://github.com/facebook/dataloader